# how to compute 'y' in 2^y = 2^q0 + ... + 2^qn efficiently in C++?

Tags: c++, math

I have equation:

```
2^y = 2^q0 + ... 2^qn
```

n is a arbitrary integer number(there are arbitrary number of 'q's). the value for 'q's can be as big as 500 which 2^q couldn't store in integer or long variable types. I want to compute 'y' other than the method below, because of storage capacity problem :

```
log2(2^q0 + ... + 2^qn)
```

how can i compute 'y' in efficient way in C++. is there anyway to compute 'y' with simple arithmetic operations on 'q's ?!

EDIT: 'q's are non negative, I look for 2 versions of this problem: 'q's are integer, 'q's are double

Comment: Are the 'q's integers? Are they non-negative?

Comment: they are non negative.

Comment: actually i want to do it in 2 versions: qs are integers, and qs are doubles

Comment: Do you have a requirement for the precision of y? In particular, when `y` ins integral and each `q` is unique, `y=max_element(q[])` because `2 * 2^q_max` > `2^y`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First sort `qi`s. Let's say minimum is `p`, subtract `p` from all `qi`s. You may check if the `qi`s form a Arithmetic serie, if you're lucky and they form such serie, you have a mathematical shortcut, but otherwise since AFAIK there is no mathematical rule to simplify `log(a1 + a2 + ... + ak)` the best way to compute `y` is this:

Since you have `qi`s sorted, you can compute `sum = 1 + 2 ^ (q1-p) + 2 ^ (q2-p) + ...` in a dynamic-algorithm-like way(i.e using previous results to compute next term).

```
prev_exp = 0;
prev_term = 1;
this_term = 0;
sum = 1;
// p is previously subtracted from q[i]s
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
  this_term = prev_term * (1 << (q[i] - prev_exp)); // 2 ^ m = (1 << m)
  prev_term = this_term;
  prev_exp = q[i] - prev_exp;
  sum += this_term;
}
```

`y` can be computed as `y = p + log2(sum)`

Note that you are also summing the small numbers first. That will help floating point precision.

I was editing this answer to add another solution based on divide-and-conquer type of algorithms but i couldn't finish it, but i guess if i leave it in a hidden block(spoiler block in this site's editor naming) somebody can finish off or improve this part of answer. feel free to edit.

> In case of maximum of `q[i]`s is so larger than minimum of them(i.e
>  `p`), you can use divide and conquer algorithm, recursively compute
>  `sum1 = 1 + 2^(q[1]-p) + .... + 2^(q[n/2]-p)` and `sum2 = 2^(q[n/2 +
>  1]-p) + ... + 2 ^ (q[n-1] - p)` you can factorize `2^(q[n/2 + 1]-p)`
>  here too. then you'll have:
>  
>  `y = p + log2(sum1 + sum2) = p + log2(sum1 + 2^p' sum2')` where `p'`
>  is `q[n/2 + 1]-p`. It helps you to keep your numbers smaller.

Comment: Thank you MJafar Mash, your solution may help in some situations but assume this: p = 4 and the maximum of qi = 500. in this matter, it doesn't help alot

Comment: you still have a problem when qi-p > 64 (number of bits in a long); so this does not really help much

Comment: @Shnd: It does help considerably. 2^500 is within the limit of a floating point double and the fact that small numbers are being added first improves the accuracy of the answer. You ought to accept this.

Comment: Actually @pandrei is right, but Mjafar mash suggestion was really good

Comment: This answer can work in many practicle examples, but is is not correct in formal sense. A double does not have 500 bit precision. if you add 2^0 more than 2^52 times, you are no more able to sum up (and adding 2^0 wont change anymore the result).  How long your sum can be?

Comment: @Bathsheba actually no he shouldn't this solution does not solve the problem it only solves it for a very limited number of cases. PLUS the fact that the implementation is overly complicated; Sum should be computed as 1<<(qi-p) i=[0..N]; no need for all those other operations

Answer (score 1):

That's clearly a problem that cannot be afforded inside the standard or built-in types.

You can observe that, 2^qx is a 1 shifted qx bits on the left and log2(y) is the number of right shift you have to take before the number becomes one.
You can then observe that adding two numbers in overflow makes the result lesser than the addedns and a 1 to propagate on the left.

At this point you can:

- implement a class that stores 500 bits (you can use an `unsigned x[1+500/sizef(unsigned)])`)
- give that class an explicit constructor taking a `unsigned q` that sets the appropriate bit (divide q by sizeof(unsigned) to determine the index, and use modulous to determin the remaining shift)
- implement the + operator for your "big interger" (just sum the sub-integers starting from the last and propagate the carry if any - that is: if the sum is lower then the addends)
- implement the log2 operation by counting the position of the overall highmost 1.

---

In case you can ensure the various qi don't repeat, there is no need of such an arithmetic: All you have to do is just remember the higest one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take powers or multiply to take integral power of 2: just shift 1 by appropriate amount. I think the following code would be the most efficient:

```
double ComputeY( vector<unsigned> Qs )
{
    unsigned sum = 0;
    for( vector<unsigned>::iterator it = Qs.begin(); it != Qs.end(); ++it )
    {
        int q = *it; // Get the next q
        int two_power_q = 1 << q; // This is the key: 2^q == 1 << q
        sum += two_power_q;
    }

    double y = log2( sum ); // need double because the result may not be integer
    return y; 
}
```

Comment: This is the same as the "naive" implementation already mentioned in the question. How is it an answer? Also, it breaks down for `(1<<q) > INT_MAX`, which is to be expected when q=500.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is similar to MJafar Mash's solution, but avoids infinity  (Eg: If adjacent exponents have a huge difference { 0, 1024 }).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
double logarithm(const std::vector<T>& sorted_exponents) {
    typedef typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type Unsigned;
    const unsigned digits = 32;
    // Evaluate sum(2^sorted_exponents[i]) = sum * 2^scale*digits
    double sum = 0;
    Unsigned scale = 0;
    for(Unsigned e : sorted_exponents) {
        // Evaluate e = 2^e * 2^(s*digits)
        Unsigned s = e / digits;
        e %= digits;
        sum = double(uint32_t(1) << e) + sum / pow(2.0, double(s - scale)*digits);
        scale = s;
    }
    return std::log2(sum) + double(scale)*digits;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1);
    std::vector<int> v;
    unsigned size = 500;
    for(unsigned max_exponent = 1; max_exponent < 10000000; max_exponent *= 10) {
        v.clear();
        v.reserve(size);
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            v.push_back(std::rand() % max_exponent);
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
        double log = logarithm(v);
        std::cout << "Maximal Exponent: " << v.back() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "       Logarithm: " << log;
        std::cout <<  std::endl;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Maximal Exponent: 0
       Logarithm: 8.965784284662087
Maximal Exponent: 9
       Logarithm: 15.58590144969077
Maximal Exponent: 99
       Logarithm: 102.4678312951325
Maximal Exponent: 997
       Logarithm: 997.5899323737988
Maximal Exponent: 9999
       Logarithm: 9999.000000002708
Maximal Exponent: 99960
       Logarithm: 99960.32192809488
Maximal Exponent: 998055
       Logarithm: 998055
```

Answer (score 0):

let's digest what is asking here.

```
  qn   binary
2^0 => 00000001
2^1 => 00000010
2^2 => 00000100
---------------
sum => 00000111
y => log2(sum) => 2
```

That mean it is asking where is the position of left most binary 1 after summing all the 2^q0 + ... 2^qn
and qn is the position of the binary digit 1 in each 2^qn.

Other have pointed out, if all in q are unique, y = max_element(q).

If that is not the case, we have to calculate the sum and find the left most binary digit 1.
To calculate the sum we don't need retain all the digit, just the left most one.

Let's convert each 2^qn to binary and group each of the element in q by where it's digit 1 falls into.
If the digit 1 falls into the first 48 digit put it in group 0, if it falls in second 48 digit put it in group 1 and so on.
Then we calculate sum of group 0 and carry forward all the overflow digits to next group until we calculate the last group.

Group of 48 digit is chosen so that it can be calculated using int64 with the 8 MSB bit as carrie forward.
In the last group, find the position of left most digit 1: **left_most_bit**.
Then value of **y = left_most_bit + group_number * 48**

```
int function(vector<int> const& q)
{
    vector<int> group;

    // group each element in q
    for(int i=0; i<q.size(); ++i)
    {
        group[i] = q[i] / 48;
    }

    // find the maximum group
    int group_max = std::max_element(group.begin(), group.end());
    int64 sum = 0;

    for(int g=0; g<=group_max; ++g)
    {
        // calculate group of 48 bits
        for(int i=0; i<q.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(group[i] == g)  // is this elementin the group that we are calculating?
            {
                int pos_of_digit_1 = q[i] - g * 48;
                sum += (1 << pos_of_digit_1);   // convert to value and sum it.
            }
        }
        sum = sum >> 48;    // carrie forward the 8 MSB bits
    }

    int pos_of_left_most_1 = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<64; ++i)
    {
        if((sum << i) & 0x8000000000000000);
        {
            pos_of_left_most_1 = 64 - i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return group_max * 48 + pos_of_left_most_1;
}
```

This answer is for integer value y and q.  For floating point value, we can't do it this way.